# Scipy - Inverse Sampling Method from custom probability density function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to perform an inverse sampling from a custom probability density function (PDF). I am just wondering if this even possible, i.e. integrating the PDF, inverting the result and then solving it for a given uniform number. The PDF has the shape  f(x, alpha, mean(x))=(1/Gamma(alpha+1)(x))((x*(alpha+1)/mean(x))^(alpha+1))exp(-(alpha+1)*(x/mean(x)) where x > 0. From the shape the only values sub-150 are relevant, and for what I am trying to do the sub-80 values are good enough. Extending the range shouldnt be too hard though.

I have tried to do the inversion method, but only found a numerical way to do the integral, which isnt necessarily helpful considering that I need to invert the function to solve:

u = integral(f(x, alpha, mean(x))dx) from 0 to y, where y is unknown and u is uniform random variable between 0 and 1.

The integral has a gamma function and an incomplete gamma function, so trying to invert it is kind of a mess. Any help is welcome.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Cheers

Comment: What is the domain of your PDF? The function you have is non-normalizable unless you restrict the domain somehow.

Comment: Sorry the complete PDF is: 
(1/Gamma(alpha+1)(x))((x*(alpha+1)/mean(x))^(alpha+1))exp(-(alpha+1)*(x/mean(x))
and the domain is 0 to inf

Comment: Is your mean(x) just a parameter mean_x? Given x is just the point where the pdf is evaluated, the mean of x is just x.

Comment: It is a parameter that is to be assumed, so mean(x) != x

Comment: Can you write your pdf in unambiguous form, e.g. as a python expression? My impression is that after standardizing, the pdf just looks like a standard gamma pdf, which is in numpy.random and in scipy.stats.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean that you're trying to randomly choose values which will be distributed according to your PDF, then yes, it is possible. This is described on Wikipedia as [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). Basically, it's just what you said: integrate the PDF to produce the cumulative distribution (CDF), invert it (which can be done ahead of time), and then choose a random number and run it through the inverted CDF.

If your domain is 0 to positive infinity, your distribution appears to match the [gamma distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.gamma.html#numpy.random.gamma) which is built into Numpy and Scipy, with `theta = 1/alpha` and `k = alpha+1`.

Comment: How can I invert it beforehand? I am having trouble doing the inversion because the integral gives me a incomplete Gamma Function

Comment: You don't actually have to do the inversion yourself, because you can just use Numpy's gamma distribution to directly obtain values distributed according to your desired PDF. But if you did have to do the inversion, I'd go with a lookup table and linear interpolation between the points.

Comment: My main problem is that I am only looking for values between 0 and about 150, so I technically dont need to integrate from 0 to inf. I am just not getting passed the incomplete gamma function. I know I can integrate numerical, but am not sure if I can than sample from that.

Comment: I think you may have to edit your question with more detail on what you're trying.